# is it possible to retrieve VS/Intellij/PyCharm projects in a new pc?

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, intellij-idea, pycharm

My pc got stolen and i was wondering if there's a way to retrieve all my Visual Studio and Intellij projects according to my user account. I used VS2014 and Intellij 2015 with Windows 10. My new pc also has Windows 10.

Comment: Visual Studio 2014 doesn't exist by the way.

Answer (score 1):

> My pc got stolen and i was wondering if there's a way to retrieve all
>   my Visual Studio and Intellij projects according to my user account. I
>   used VS2014 and Intellij 2015 with Windows 10. My new pc also has
>   Windows 10.

If you didn't store those projects in any other location they only existed on your PC.